# Получение хендлов элементов управления чужой формы

Tags: winapi, delphi

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. Передо мной стоит такая дилема: есть некий процесс, который что то делает и периодически возвращает прогресс своей деятельности. Есть некое окно, которое собственно с процессом никак не связано. В этом окне нужно отображать прогресс деятельности процесса. Решил сделать так: из под процесса искать нужную форму с помощью FindWindow, далее получить хендл интересующего меня элемента управления (в данном случае это Tlabel, и он там один) и послеть найденому хендлу виндовое сообщение со всей нужной инфой. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как зная хендл окна получить хендл какого-либо из его элементов управления. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону GetWindow. 
Но есть одно "но": TLabel не является Windows-компонентом, то есть не имеет хэндла (дескриптора) и соответственно с ним не работают АПИ-функции предназначенные для работы с окнами.
Решение: если есть возможность, то перепишите "некий процесс" - вместо TLabel используйте TEdit.

Answer (score 1):

вон оно что... я использовал такой метод:

`var
 SearchedWnd : HWND;
 Lbl : HWND;
begin
 SearchedWnd := FindWindow('TSomeForm', nil);
 Lbl := FindWindowEx(SearchedWnd, 0, 'TLabel', nil);
 SendMessage(lbl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, lParam('Распознано страниц   '+IntToStr(ScanCount)));
end;`

не работало
переписал (и заменил соответственно на форме)

`var
 SearchedWnd : HWND;
 Lbl : HWND;
begin
 SearchedWnd := FindWindow('TSomeForm', nil);
 Lbl := FindWindowEx(SearchedWnd, 0, 'TEdit', nil);
 SendMessage(lbl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, lParam('Распознано страниц   '+IntToStr(ScanCount)));
end;`

заработало. спасибо за подсказку